# How to build react components css

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, react-component

I developed a component using react, Use babel to build into the lib directory.

But my css I do not know how to build it, I need help Thanks.

My Code:

"scripts": {
   "build": "./node_modules/.bin/babel ./src --out-dir ./lib"
}

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to your code you need to have a file called index.scss in the same directory as the page in your screenshot. That would be a Sass file that compiles to CSS (https://sass-lang.com). If you are not using Sass, you need to replace the "required" file with whatever file you are using for your css  (e.g. index.css). I presume you are not asking how to use css itself in conjunction with your html.

Comment: I hope I use my component this way      var exampie = require('myComponent')  Css file is no longer introduced alone, But I have a CSS file in my source code, I do not know how to organize,Thank you